# how to set up store data to check guards in routes in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

simply importing store to routes.js bringing not defined error.

How can bring the store state values in vue navigation guard checks?

```
import store from '../store/store';

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
      if (!store.state.auth.user) {
        next('/login')
      } else {
        next()
      }
    } else {
      next()
    }
  })
```

Comment: why don't you put that `if` logic into the `next` you can pass a function instead https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards you

Comment: Maybe try `this.$store.state.auth.user`? Although this seems like it could be a similar problem (https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-vuex/issues/37).